# Performance difference search on INT or TEXT in SQLite 3

Tags: database, performance, types, sqlite

I'm a little bit confused about SQLite 3 type system. SQLite 2  was typeless with only exception of INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. I don't get if SQLite 3 are same or not..

I have in my table PRIMARY KEY of INT and TEXT values. I do a lot of operation based on those keys. Will it be any difference in performance if I will make key INT and INT in SQLite 3?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

You should use whatever data type your keys actually have; otherwise, the values would have to be converted.

Comment: I was thinking on moving the TEXT column to another table, where will be that column and INT id, and use that id as composite key in first table, that is a way how I can have INT and INT key instead of INT and TEXT

Comment: For this case, any performance difference depend on the actual data.